Can you make a drag and drop while still using jQuery grid?
I'm trying to make divs that can be moved around freely and the divs inside should be drag and drop. Is there anyway of doing this?
I have tried to make the divs draggable with jQuery .draggable({ grid: [80, 80] });, but then I can't make drag and drop between the divs (draggabaleDiv1 and dragabaleDiv2). What am I doing wrong? Is this possible?
This is an example:


let container = document.createElement('div');
container.classList.add('container');
container.style.display = 'flex';
container.style.width = '50vw';
container.style.height = '500px';
container.style.flexDirection = 'row';
container.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
container.style.border = '10px solid black';

const div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.classList.add('div1');
div1.style.width = '25vw';
div1.style.height = '25vh';
div1.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
div1.style.margin = '10px';
div1.style.border = '10px solid black'


// if u coment out the next line, the div will be draggable, but not between them. how can i do that? 
$(div1).draggable({ grid: [80, 80] }); // why cant i make a draganddropp between divs with jQuery UI draggable.

const div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.classList.add('dropzone');
div2.style.width = '25vw';
div2.style.height = '25vh';
div2.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
div2.style.margin = '10px';
div2.style.border = '10px solid black';


const draggableDiv1 = document.createElement('div');
draggableDiv1.classList.add('drag');
draggableDiv1.textContent = 'Dragme';
draggableDiv1.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
draggableDiv1.style.margin = '10px';
draggableDiv1.style.border = '2px solid black';
draggableDiv1.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

const draggableDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
draggableDiv2.classList.add('draggable');
draggableDiv2.textContent = 'Dragme too!';
draggableDiv2.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
draggableDiv2.style.margin = '10px';
draggableDiv2.style.border = '2px solid black';
draggableDiv2.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

document.body.append(container);
container.appendChild(div1);
container.appendChild(div2);
div1.appendChild(draggableDiv1);
div1.appendChild(draggableDiv2);


draggableDiv1.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
draggableDiv2.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);


div1.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
div1.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
div1.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
div1.addEventListener('drop', drop);
div2.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
div2.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
div2.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
div2.addEventListener('drop', drop);



draggableDiv1.id = 'draggable1';
draggableDiv2.id = 'draggable2';


draggableDiv1.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
draggableDiv2.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);


div1.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
div1.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
div1.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
div1.addEventListener('drop', drop);
div2.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
div2.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
div2.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
div2.addEventListener('drop', drop);


function dragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', event.target.id);
}

function dragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function dragEnter(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.target.style.border = '2px dashed black'; 
}

function dragLeave(event) {
    event.target.style.border = 'none'; 
}

function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
    const draggableElement = document.getElementById(data);
    event.target.style.border = 'none';
    if (event.target.classList.contains('dropzone')) {
        event.target.appendChild(draggableElement);
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Drag and Drop Grid</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  
  
</body>
</html>



